# 2.83: How to enable depression

Tags: 3d-view

[image]

In the above image there are depressions (ex: pointed by the red arrows). On the other hand, in the below image same points are flat.

[image]

So how can I enable the depressions? I want to do that cause it helps me seeing easily objects. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could enable the *Wireframe* option in the *Viewport Overlays* panel:

[image]

Or enable the Shadow option in the *Viewport Shading* panel:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your advice, that solved my problem.